# Do UTF-8 encoded HTML documents ususally start with a BOM?

Tags: html, utf-8, byte-order-mark

For a Rich Text (RTF) to HTML / XHTML converter I am writing, which generates UTF-8 encoded HTML pages, I consider to add the option to include a BOM.

But should the generation of a BOM be disabled or enabled by default for UTF-8 encoded HTML documents? If the majority of web pages are delivered without BOM, I would set the default generator configuration to 'no BOM'.

Comment: A BOM for **UTF-8**?? Why? Even the unicode standard itself recommends against doing that.

Comment: @Kerrek SB thanks for the hint - I knew that a BOM is not required for regular XML files (where UTF-8 is the default) and that that it can bring trouble with many applications (PHP, Unix shells). I needed some more reasons against it in HTML documents, as the the string functions in Delphi's run time library create a BOM for UTF-8 by default, so that I can explain why the BOM is not needed (or not recommended).

Comment: I am so not researching before asking :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not usual and [can cause problems](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-utf8-bom.en).

I would recommend disabling it by default.